# How to Develop Applications for Nokia X3-02?

Tags: qt, mobile, jar, symbian, nokia

I want to know about the development procedures of Applications for Nokia X3-02.
I wish to develop a twitter feed apps for my mobile. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

It would absolutely be possible to create a twitter application for your phone. You can download the SDK for your phone at the link here: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Develop/Java/

The twitter API is not the best, but you can find it here: http://dev.twitter.com/ .

Good Luck